# Nvidia Drivers - Synaptic

Tags: installation, drivers, nvidia, synaptic

So I am in synaptic package manager and want to install a new Nvidia driver

I see:

- Nvidia-319
- Nvidia-319-updates

which one should I pick? Which on is the non-free proprietary one?

I have a gtx580.

Answer (score 11):

To know which one should you pick, use the following command in terminal:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
```

It will return the recommended video driver for your machine.

If `ubuntu-drivers` is not found, run the following command in terminal to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-drivers-common
```

Comment: jan@jan-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Y550:~$ ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended
ubuntu-drivers: command not found

Comment: @user320 You can find it in Ubuntu Software Center: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ubuntu-drivers-common/