# USB 3.0 port being seen as a USB 2.0 port

Tags: usb, 18.04

As the title says, my system doesn't seem to recognize my USB 3.0. It instead claims to be a 2.0. Any help would be appreciated!

My computer is the Asus Q200E. It's pretty bad, but it works for school. Except for this damn usb 3.0 port

```
    lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 25, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 14, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

[pic from hardinfo (highlighted part is what's connected to the supposed 3.0 port)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cou58.png)

[proof port and usb a are both 3.0 compatible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQaB.jpg)

Comment: Can you [edit](https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142) your question and copy and paste the output of `sudo lsusb -t` from a terminal window?

Comment: `Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M` is USB 3.0.  The 5000M means 5GHz for the speed.  To obtain those speeds you need to plug in an actual device that is USB 3.0.  Plugging in a USB 2.0 device into a 3.0 port will slow down to the 480Mb of USB 2.0.

Comment: Hmm weird, I geuss I thought my device was USB 3.0 compatible, but I can't find anywhere that says it is. My mistake, thanks for the info!

Comment: My bad, that's supposed to be 5Gb not 5GHz.  Anyway, you can run that lsusb command again with your device plugged in and see.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the following procedures will fix your problem right away.

1. Open terminal
2. Backup your grub config by entering `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup` (note: this is the location of the grub config in recent Ubuntu versions, the location of your file may differ based on distro and version)
3. Open your grub file: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
4. Find the line that begins with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add `iommu=soft` after `"quiet splash"` and before the quotation mark `"quiet splash iommu=soft"`.
5. Save the file by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> and then exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>
6. Enter `update-grub` in terminal and hit enter to update your grub.cfg
7. Restart your machine to let the changes take place.

Comment: Would you go into a bit more detailed explanation on how adding `iommu=soft` would solve the problem?

Comment: The iommu=soft parameter instructs the Linux kernel to use a software-based Input/Output Memory Management Unit (IOMMU) instead of the hardware-based one. This is useful for resolving compatibility or performance issues with devices like USB controllers or graphics cards that require direct memory access (DMA), especially in systems with hardware virtualization challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Crazy suggestion: check your cable.  It might be that your USB cable can't handle gbps and so everything is negotiating to 480mbps of USB2.

It's normal/standard for the XHCI driver to expose both a USB 2 hub and a USB 3 hub in `lsusb`.  You have both - the `5000M` entry is USB 3.  When you plug something in, it will appear under one or the other hub, depending on how fast it is.  So it looks like maybe your linux system is all good, but you haven't successfully plugged in a USB 3 capable system (device+cable) yet.