# nVidia 390.48 to 396.24 and no cuda found in Blender

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, blender

Under 390.48 everything worked well in Blender and having duo Intel-nVidia I could work under Intel by prime-select and have nVidia activated in Blender. After update to 396.24 there's no cuda found and even I go back to 390.48 it's still the issue. Even I will switch to nVidia entirely by prime-select nvidia the cuda still isn't detected. I wonder if there may be other areas of ubuntu internal or other apps/dependencies which could break nVidia cuda detection? Any version of Blender checked. No any major ingerentions made in system internally just standard updates coming daily.

Comment: Have you had a chance to look through the answer on this similar [Blender CUDA question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030886/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-18-04-with-coffee-lake-is-it-suppo/1030901#1030901)

Comment: Yes, it helped, now it's as usuall with additional cuda toolkit installed and prime-select on nvidia. The thing is former drivers worked alone giving the cuda and under 390.48 driver it was even improved like You could set by prime-select to Intel but while working under Blender the cuda was somehow detected so nVidia was active on demand. I would think that it was maybe an accidental mistake in nVidia driver like pseudo improvement but somehow my laptop worked more silently than usual so like Intel was in use all time with all cuda capabilities available under Blender. Like under Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the nvidia-cuda-toolkit package? If not type the following into terminal:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Comment: Maybe I'll try this, thanks for hint, but the thing is I didn't need this package to be installed previously as the nVidia driver alone was just enough for the work done.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that the default repository version of blender in Ubuntu does not contain precompiled cuda kernels, and thus requires `cuda-toolkit` to enable GPU rendering.

Installing blender from [Thomas Shiex's ppa](https://launchpad.net/~thomas-schiex/+archive/ubuntu/blender) however pulls precomplied cuda kernels so you can avoid the initial kernel compilation as well as the installation of cuda-toolkit.

If you've just updated ubuntu your ppa should have been disabled and your blender has been probably replaced by the official ubuntu package, thus "removing" cuda support if you don't have cuda-toolkit already installed.

Comment: Well, I use that ppa You've cited but anyway had to install cuda-toolkit. For me more mysterious is how former nVidia driver worked as I could set Intel as primary by prime-select but have nVidia cuda enabled in Blender anyway...usually it's known under linux You can have either Intel or nVidia at the same time instead of them both like under Windows.