# Ubuntu 18.04 running in low graphics after adding nomodeset in grub

Tags: nvidia, graphics, 18.04

few days back i tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 on my Notebook computer. But the installation process freezes in initial phrase. So someone suggest me to add nomodeset in grub.
After adding nomodeset in grub. Ubuntu installed successfully. but after login i see that the ubuntu desktop is running in low graphics. 
Some poss says that i had to install NVIDIA drivers(As notebok has NVIDIA Geforce 520M card). I followed their instructions but it crashes OS.

here are sykumar-hcl-me-laptop

```
    description: Laptop
    product: HCL ME Laptop (0)
    vendor: HCL Infosystems Limited
    version: 1.0
    serial: SSN12345678901234567
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=laptop family=PEGA Family sku=0
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: HCL ME Laptop
       vendor: HCL
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0
       serial: BSN12345678901234567
       slot: MIDDLE
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: 206
          date: 05/06/2011
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2370M CPU @ 2.40GHz
          serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 987MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=1 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 3MiB
             capacity: 3MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 41
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: V01D3S82GB26826813
             vendor: 0000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 00000000
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: HMT325S6CFR8C-H9
             vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
             physical id: 1
             serial: 0463502E
             slot: DIMM2
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 09
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f3000000-f40fffff ioport:d0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display UNCLAIMED
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GF108M [GeForce GT 520M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f3000000-f3ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f4000000-f407ffff
        *-display UNCLAIMED
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f4400000-f47fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:e000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:30 memory:f700a000-f700a00f
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7008000-f70083ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Video
                      product: USB2.0 UVC 1.3M Webcam
                      vendor: Generic
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@1:1.1
                      version: 1.05
                      serial: 200901010001
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: AR3011 Bluetooth
                      vendor: Atheros Communications, Inc.
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@1:1.2
                      version: 0.01
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:f7000000-f7003fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:c000(size=4096) memory:f6600000-f6ffffff ioport:e4200000(size=10485760)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.1
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:b000(size=4096) memory:f5c00000-f65fffff ioport:e3700000(size=10485760)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlp3s0
                version: 01
                serial: 74:2f:68:de:25:ac
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.43.221 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:17 memory:f5c00000-f5c0ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:a000(size=4096) memory:f5200000-f5bfffff ioport:e2c00000(size=10485760)
           *-usb
                description: USB controller
                product: uPD720200 USB 3.0 Host Controller
                vendor: NEC Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                version: 04
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
                resources: irq:19 memory:f5200000-f5201fff
              *-usbhost:0
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 0
                   bus info: usb@3
                   logical name: usb3
                   version: 4.15
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: USB Receiver
                      vendor: Logitech
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@3:1
                      version: 15.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=98mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usbhost:1
                   product: xHCI Host Controller
                   vendor: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic xhci-hcd
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4
                   logical name: usb4
                   version: 4.15
                   capabilities: usb-3.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: b5
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:9000(size=4096) memory:f4800000-f51fffff ioport:e2100000(size=10485760)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: enp5s0
                version: c0
                serial: 00:e0:00:c0:d7:c2
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
                resources: irq:32 memory:f4800000-f483ffff ioport:9000(size=128)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7007000-f70073ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 05
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:29 ioport:e0b0(size=8) ioport:e0a0(size=4) ioport:e090(size=8) ioport:e080(size=4) ioport:e060(size=32) memory:f7006000-f70067ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 05
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7005000-f70050ff ioport:e040(size=32)
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MK5059GS
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1A
             serial: 42P4Y3AYF
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096 signature=335c3906
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 3ac7a052-b69e-8a40-aa5f-dd5713d973d5
                size: 116GiB
                capacity: 116GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2018-03-23 18:52:49 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 349GiB
                capacity: 349GiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume:0
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: d49dd963-c29f-b747-8f23-9302e95feabc
                   size: 115GiB
                   capacity: 115GiB
                   capabilities: ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-07-11 20:48:40 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
              *-logicalvolume:1
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 6
                   logical name: /dev/sda6
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: 9660e75a-32a3-1943-82e9-58068b0fb223
                   size: 116GiB
                   capacity: 116GiB
                   capabilities: ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2014-03-29 09:42:17 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
              *-logicalvolume:2
                   description: Windows NTFS volume
                   physical id: 7
                   logical name: /dev/sda7
                   version: 3.1
                   serial: d081259c-31bb-3a40-954b-1ddcda463abe
                   size: 68GiB
                   capacity: 68GiB
                   capabilities: ntfs initialized
                   configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2016-03-04 12:48:18 filesystem=ntfs state=clean
              *-logicalvolume:3
                   description: EXT4 volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 8
                   logical name: /dev/sda8
                   logical name: /
                   version: 1.0
                   serial: 5141c50c-145c-4780-80b2-fbd730da6359
                   size: 48GiB
                   capacity: 48GiB
                   capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                   configuration: created=2018-05-02 10:55:31 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-05-07 10:16:49 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered mounted=2018-05-07 10:16:53 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD A  DS8A5S
             vendor: Slimtype
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: WP57
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
stem hardware information:-
```

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142 as I have the video driver installation for Ubuntu 18.04 in the bottom half of that answer.

Comment: it installs but.. after using nvidia-smi command it shows following error:-    NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Hmmmm, according to https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa you might need either the `nvidia-340` or `nvidia-304` driver.  I am not sure as they don't exactly have your chipset listed.  Try either one of those two.  I believe that the `nvidia-smi` is with the `nvidia-340` but not with the `nvidia-304`.  As far as the Intel graphics go, the built in drivers should be handling that one on its own.

Comment: As i tried to install Nvidia-driver-340   it says unable to locate package

Comment: That would just be `nvidia-340`  The `nvidia-driver-39x` is for the newest ones in 18.04.

Comment: Opps.. it sucks. After installing nvidia-340.. Ubuntu freezes after displaying some message....the last message is..."Starting Gnome display manager. Dispatcher Services....ystem changes.pp link was shut down... "