# Nvidia Plugin causing black screen on Ubuntu LTS 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

I'm having trouble with Nvidia drivers on my [Acer Predator Helios 300](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-series/predatorhelios300). It has an NVIDIA GeForce Gtx 1060. I've installed the drivers for the 440, 430, 410 and 390, and they all have the same trouble. When I boot, it stays on a black screen and if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, a blinking underline appears

The only way for me to boot Linux is by selecting prime-select intel and then changing again to Nvidia after the boot. In this case, Nvidia-smi works normally and I can even use Cuda. When I reboot, however, the error persists, and I have to select Intel again.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with the latest kernel (5.0)

I've already tested these questions { [[1](https://www.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/predator-series/predatorhelios300)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1129516/black-screen-at-boot-after-nvidia-driver-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts), [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744419/blank-screen-after-nvidia-install), [[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085042/ubuntu-18-10-installing-nvidia-drivers-leads-to-black-screen-after-grub), [[4]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033784/ubuntu-ugrade-17-10-to-18-04-nvidia-black-screen) } without success.

Comment: see if this helps ... https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1068626/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/

Comment: it worked, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue these steps

```
sudo rm  /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime # make sure nvidia-prime is installed
sudo prime-select nvidia # switch to nvidia
sudo rm /lib/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia.conf # remove stray blacklist files
sudo update-initramfs -u # update the initrd
sudo reboot
```

see further discussion at https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1068626/black-screen-after-install-of-nvidia-driver-ubuntu/