# Xubuntu 18.04: Nvidia causes black screen after boot

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, nvidia

I have a fresh installation of Xubuntu 18.04. I have installed driver `nvidia-driver-440`. When I switch to Nvidia (`prime-select nvidia`) my system will not boot. It will stop at black screen with a blinking white cursor. The only way to get back is to run in recovery mode and switch to intel back. Is there a way to fix this issue?

```
$: sudo lshw -c Display

  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I found similar problem [Nvidia Plugin causing black screen on Ubuntu LTS 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198581/nvidia-plugin-causing-black-screen-on-ubuntu-lts-18-04) but the solution doesn't help me

### Update

Looks like the problem is not in Linux and drivers. I have same problem while running Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @K7AAY doesnt work