# NVIDIA driver not installing

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

It has been about 2 weeks since i upgraded ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04.
This brought a bunch of problems (like freezing, black startup screen, login loops), i found other people associate with the NVIDIA driver.
I have tried every solution i could find (without any progress) and now it's like not seeing the forest for the trees.

I have an Acer Aspire 7 laptop with NVIDIA GeForce 1050.
As far as i know, the proprietary driver 384.111 seemed to work on 17.10, but each time after i upgrade from there, it disapears.
I have tried to install this driver, and a few other, but all give the same error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load the 'nvidia-drm' kernel module
```

Going from the log, i seem to get the same warning everytime when it's installing 'NVIDIA Acelerated Grahics Driver for Linux-x86_64':

```
/sbin.ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so/conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_EGL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin.ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so/conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
```

That is the only lead i have as far as i can think of.
How can i go on from this?

Comment: Try https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142 where the driver install for 18.04 is the last half of the answer.

Comment: While it does seem to install the driver properly, when i enter the command: nvidia-smi, i get the error: 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

Comment: Did you reboot after installing the driver?

Comment: Yes, i did. reboot then ran nvidia-smi.

Comment: Make sure that `dkms` is installed on your system.  Also, according to https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1028367/linux/unable-to-load-the-nvidia-drm-kernel-module-on-ubuntu-16-04/ it looks as though the `nvidia-drm` failing to load might need adding `acpi_osi=Linux` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=` line in the `/etc/default/grub` file.

Comment: dkms were already up to date, added the line. Still fails to communicate.

Comment: I am actually out of ideas on this one.  My install became a clean install because my upgrade install was a nightmare trying to get stuff fixed.  When I clean installed it, the drivers and all that worked after installing them that way.  The `nvidia-driver-390` and `nvidia-driver-396` are for the newest cards they have.  One last thing I guess you could try is purging all nvidia drivers `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*` before trying to install again.

Comment: I did, many times, have also clean installed numerous times. Well, i have to install 17.10 and then upgrade every time, because i can't use a bootable 18 because it keeps freezing. I don't know if that changes anything even though it shouldn't. Thanks for your troubles anyways.

Comment: You could wait till Canonical releases the first point (18.04.1) before upgrading.  That is actually what I am going to do with my systems from now on for the ones I actually care about.  The first point release is scheduled for late July 2018.  Canonical themselves makes the 18.04.1 upgrade available to 16.04 systems then.  I think it is good to let them work out any bugs they might still be having.

Comment: Well, that's not very satisfying, but i believe waiting is for the best. Going to go for 16 now.