# Kubuntu 18.04 no more GUI after upgrade from 17.10

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, gui, sddm

I upgraded Kubuntu from 17.10 to 18.04 LTS today. Upgrade went well, until the system rebooted. I got the Kubuntu splash screen, but then: nothing. Black screen. I can however enter TTY 2-6 (1,7,8 not responding). I'm using a laptop with both Intel integrated graphics and NVidia GeForce GT 520 MX graphics card.

I tried:

- `apt update && apt dist-upgrade`
- reconfigure sddm (`dpkg-reconfigure sddm`)
- installing different NVidia drivers, as I had problems with the driver last time I installed ubuntu. (nvidia-304- not able to install,nvidia-driver-390, didn't help. nvidia-340: and nouveau, also didn't help
- Adding 'nomodeset' to `/etc/default/grub`: no help
- `startx` to start the Xserver myself. This results in an error, being that Xserver is not able to start. `kstart plasma-desktop` shows the following error

  > cannot connect to X server

What would be the right way to do it?

Comment: Shameless Plug: There are other reasons why you could also end up without a GUI. [This post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1029509/535457) may also be relevant and/or of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of trying, I got the GUI working again, thanks to these two posts:

- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391150
- https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1033140/kubuntu-18-04-gives-black-screen-when-sddm-starts-no-login-/?offset=6

So, this turned out to be a NVidia-driver issue. I reinstalled the NVidia 390 driver, and added the lines suggested in the posts above to the `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup`-file, and in the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`-file, a line (`Driver "nvidia"`) in `Section "Device"` was commented-out, which I enabled again. Rebooted succesfully into the GUI.

Comment: Please improve your answer such that if the remote URLs cease to exist your answer here will continue to be useful independently of them.