# Overheating in Kubuntu 18.04 - Lenovo Ideapad 330-15ICH

Tags: kubuntu, lenovo, overheating, temperature

I installed Kubuntu 18.04 in a new laptop (Lenovo Ideapad 330). I installed Kubuntu (along with the default Windows 10 installation) because, after a lot of tries with Ubuntu 18.04, it was not installing correctly and giving some problems.

Kubuntu works perfectly fine. Except for the fact that I have noticed that, while the computer's temperature seems normal in Windows 10 (while playing some Gamecube videogames on Dolphin emulator, which I suspect does not overheat the GPU), when running Linux it gets abnormally hot, not enough to auto-shutdown because of the heat, but enough to notice a clear difference between Windows and Linux. And this just by browsing things on the internet, or even editing some texts in gedit. I mean, this overheating is not normal at all (software related 99%)

I took a look on forums and so on, and read that installing dedicated drivers (NVIDIA ones) instead of the default ones that come with the Kubuntu distro might be a solution for this, so I downloaded the drivers (the card is an NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 1050) from here (https://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/145271). However, when trying to install the drivers, I got an error message discussed here (How to unload kernel module 'nvidia-drm'?). I followed the steps there, but to no avail, because in the end I messed up with my graphical mode. I googled like all the afternoon and part of the night, tried other few things, but nothing worked. Finally I decided to reinstall Kubuntu again. Now, after reinstalling, I'm facing the same problem. Everything works fine, but overheating for no reason.

Do you have any ideas on why? And how can I solve this issue? I would appreciate any help because, although I can use the laptop like this, I know that this will greatly shorten my laptop's life, and I think that it is something that should be fixed.

Edit: here is the output of lm-sensors

```
pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  

nouveau-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:       +511.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, hyst =  +3.0°C)
                       (crit = +105.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)
                       (emerg = +135.0°C, hyst =  +5.0°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +43.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +46.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +44.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +45.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +43.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

With a temperature of 511ºC, my computer should be melting, and it is not the case, so it seems that yes, this is drivers-graphics-related

Edit2: when I try to poweroff, the system crashes and gets stuck, and if I try to close session, there is an error, something like

```
nouveau E[Xorg[1052]] failed to idle channel 2 [Xorg[1052]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for coming back to answer your question!  If the answers on the linked question solve your problem, it would be best to close your question as a duplicate of the other.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nvidia drivers problem on Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042057/nvidia-drivers-problem-on-kubuntu-18-04)

Comment: well, actually the problem was not really solved. The poweroff-reboot problems stopped, but the overheating continues

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve all the issues by following one simple solution that I found in this post: [nvidia drivers problem on Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1042057/nvidia-drivers-problem-on-kubuntu-18-04)

I did not install any NVIDIA drivers, because this was a fresh installation, thus I did not need to remove-purge drivers, so I just run the following two commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

And it all magically solved after rebooting: lower temperatures, a normal temperature (instead of the 511 crazy degrees), and normal poweroff-rebooting-session closing (however, I needed to perform a hard reboot just after installing the drivers, because the laptop got stuck again with a normal reboot).

Comment: Edit: Not that magically. The poweroff-reboot problems disappeared, but the laptop keeps overheating. I do not know what I might try, but at least the laptop is working again.