# Failed installation of package breaks apt-get

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 for the first time. Excited to play with some GPU codes, I installed CUDA via the `deb (local)` for `17.10` option, as described on the [Nvidia CUDA page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1710&target_type=deblocal). I know `17.10 != 18.04`, but I had read of people having success with this.

I followed the installation instructions provided by Nvidia:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1710-9-2-local_9.2.88-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

The last command resulted in an error when installing `nvidia-396`:

```
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-9-2-local  nvidia-396 396.26-0ubuntu1 [80.0 MB]
(Reading database ... 167630 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-396_396.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-396 (396.26-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/./nvidia-396_396.26-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Maybe I bit off more than I could chew, so I decided to move onto less challenging things. I proceeded to install some basic packages, such as `git`, but upon doing so, I got this error:

```
> sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.26) but it is not going to be installed
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (> 1:2.17.1) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: git-man (< 1:2.17.1-.) but it is not going to be installed
 libcuda1-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-396-dev : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.26) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-opencl-icd-396 : Depends: nvidia-396 (>= 396.26) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Trying the suggested `sudo apt --fix-broken install` command results in the same `nvidia-396` error encountered above.

It appears my attempted installation of `cuda` has put `apt-get` into a state such that it will no longer install or remove any packages, due to an unmet dependencies error. Worded more simply, installing `cuda` has broken  `apt-get` completely.

How can I get my package manager working again?

Comment: Tried `sudo apt-get purge nvidia*` without any luck

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt --fix-broken install`? In your question, you omitted `sudo`?

Comment: Yes. It results in the same error mentioned earlier.

Comment: When you write "I know 17.10 != 18.04, but I had read of people having success with this." is they following the NVIDIA way or do they install it like this ? 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030886/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-18-04-with-coffee-lake-is-it-suppo/1030901

Comment: @MatsK - Note that this question is asking how to get `apt` working again (without reinstalling the OS), rather than getting CUDA toolkit installed.

Comment: I attempted to install CUDA exactly as I've described in the original question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I fix this issue only with:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
```

Comment: this fixed my problem.

Comment: it also fixed my problem, but an explanation on why it does would be nice. Thank you very much for the solution, anyways!

Comment: Thanks for this

Comment: A magician indeed. Thanks

Comment: This also worked for me but could we get some details on what exactly this is doing?

Comment: It didn't worked for me. Got ```Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-dkms-418
 nvidia-driver-418
 cuda-drivers
 cuda-runtime-10-1
 cuda-demo-suite-10-1
 cuda-10-1
 cuda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the command of StrugglingProgrammer, I had to make sure I would uninstall ***all*** cuda packages (the cuda-demo*, e.g.)

You can check which those might be with:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i cuda
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

So maybe try either

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda-* libcuda* nvidia*
```

(for the whole batch) or select more specifically like:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cuda-drivers libcuda* cuda-runtime* cuda-8-0 cuda-demo*
```

For me specifially (after trying a failed install of `cuda-8-0` and `libcudnn6`) it was:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* cuda-drivers libcuda* cuda-runtime* cuda-8-0 cuda-demo*
```

Hope that may be of help.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved this by removing everything installed in a single `apt-get remove` command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia* cuda-drivers libcuda1-396 cuda-runtime-9-2 cuda-9.2 cuda-demo-suite-9-2  cuda
```

Comment: I did the `remove --purge` approach too to fix my broken install, but when I reinstall I get the same errors as you did the first time. Did it "just work" for you?

Comment: Resolution: I was trying to install on 18.04; I gave up and have downloaded 16.04 and will try with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I excuted

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda.list'
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda_learn.list'
```

(b) Install CUDA 10.1 packages, including the CuDNN library

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cuda-10-1
sudo apt install libcudnn7
```

Check this [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:w_mwYIhFGh4J:https://medium.com/@stephengregory_69986/installing-cuda-10-1-on-ubuntu-20-04-e562a5e724a0&hl=en&gl=eg&strip=1&vwsrc=0) I didnt remove any driver just installed above stuff and updated .profile

```
nano ~/.profile
# set PATH for cuda 10.1 installation
if [ -d "/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin/" ]; then
    export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
fi
```