# How do I fix a corrupted NVIDIA driver when my package manager also seems to be corrupted?

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, package-management, graphics

Whenever I try to do something in `apt-get` or `apt`, I always get this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'nvidia-current' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-396 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-396 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-396:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-396 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-396 (= 396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-396:i386 (= 396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Then, when I try `apt --fix-broken install`, it gives me:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-396 libnvidia-gl-396:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnvidia-gl-396 libnvidia-gl-396:i386
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 72 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/32.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 147 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 236145 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-390
diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-396'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-396:i386 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Preparing to unpack .../libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
dpkg-query: no packages found matching libnvidia-gl-390
diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-396'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340'
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libnvidia-gl-396_396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried to `sudo dpkg --configure -a`, but it also gives me an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of nvidia-driver-396:
 nvidia-driver-396 depends on libnvidia-gl-396 (= 396.24.02-0ubuntu0~gpu18.04.1); however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package nvidia-driver-396 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64:
 libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64 depends on libnvidia-gl-396; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-396:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386:
 libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 depends on libnvidia-gl-396; however:
  Package libnvidia-gl-396:i386 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 nvidia-driver-396
 libnvidia-ifr1-396:amd64
 libnvidia-ifr1-396:i386
```

I also can't change from driver `nvidia-driver-396` ti the nouveau driver.
How can I fix this? I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Did you modified apt's sources.list? Did you `apt update` before?

Comment: Yes, I did, and it still showed these same errors.

Comment: Does a reboot help(if there is corruption, `fsck` should automatically run)?

Comment: You might want to try these steps: https://www.poftut.com/solve-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-error-code-1-error/

Comment: Nothing in the output show that "apt is corrupt" or that your NVIDIA driver is corrupt. It shows that you installed NVIDIA packages that are *incompatible* with your release of Ubuntu. You should uninstall those. There are no packages *missing* for `--fix-broken` to install (that's what it does).

Comment: Take a look to the output of these commands: `ubuntu-drivers devices && ubuntu-drivers list && lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12.`. I don't have that package on my Ubuntu 18.04 fresh install. You should have [this](https://pastebin.com/B6NQRuxL).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nvidia driver installation keeps failing, diversion issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067183/nvidia-driver-installation-keeps-failing-diversion-issues)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after installing Steam, Play on Linux and Lutris.
Upgrade, Remove and/or Purge the programs or the drivers I used:

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

Go to "Other software" disable all drivers other than Canonical Partners.

After that:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt autoremove
```

This solves the problem for me.
But did for sure remove and purge Steam, Play on Linux and Lutris with the next command. (you can use this for all other programs( -* after the program name will purge all properties with the program name in it))

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge (program name)
```

Answer (score 0):

most of the proposed solutions on this topic haven't worked for me, but I did find that one from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1119232/682421) did:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken
```