# Suddenly my resolution changed and I can't change it back

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I booted up my PC with Ubuntu 18.04 and noticed how resolution got lower. I tried to change it back in settings but there's no other options except current one.[Display settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD5eF.png)

Then I tried to change my Nvidia driver to X.Org driver but it didn't work as well.

My specs are [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xEDk.png), GPU is GT630.

And also there's [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdAE4.png)

Please help, I'm new to Ubuntu.

Nvidia GPU seems like to be installed.
dkms status output:

```
nvidia, 390.116: added
```

Upd:
I ran  `sudo dkms install nvidia/390.116 -k 5.3.0-26-generic` and got this output:

```
Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
unset ARCH; env NV_VERBOSE=1 'make' -j4 NV_EXCLUDE_BUILD_MODULES='' KERNEL_UNAME=5.3.0-26-generic IGNORE_XEN_PRESENCE=1 IGNORE_CC_MISMATCH=1 SYSSRC=/lib/modules/5.3.0-26-generic/build LD=/usr/bin/ld.bfd modules.........(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-dkms-390.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.3.0-26-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.116/build/make.log for more information.
```

UPD2: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2397701&p=13797330#post13797330

Comment: I just wrote this up and please see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204165/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-and-nvidia-card-low-resolution

Comment: You might have to reboot and choose the older kernel module in the grub.  There is a possibility that the 390 driver may not be compatible with the 5.3.0-26-generic kernel.  Make sure you check the `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/390.116/build/make.log` and see maybe why it crashed.

Comment: There's my crash log
https://pastebin.com/BgXwSRXS
But I have no idea what's wrong

Comment: Did you do what the log states?  Try running `cd /usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-26-generic` then run `sudo make oldconfig && sudo make prepare` then try running the `dkms` install again.

Comment: Didn't work. I also tried boot up with older kernel but it didn't work as well.

Comment: What is your video card and your computer?  Please add that info to your question.  You might be able to run a newer driver on your system.  Also, how did you install the last NVIDIA driver?  Are you using the direct one from NVIDIA or are you using the one from `graphics-drivers ppa`?

Comment: Added info in question. 

Yes, I got last Nvidia driver via `Softwave and Updates` app

Comment: Ah, OK.  Your card can go all the way to the 440 drivers.  I am looking now, but I think in order to get to the 440 drivers you need to have the ppa for the `graphics-drivers` setup.  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers`.  I have had great success with the 440 drivers right now.  After it is added it is `sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-440`

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package nvidia-drivers-440`, same goes with `nvidia-440`.

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` before trying to install after adding the repo.  Those are exactly the steps I have taken and it should work.  If it is not working, something is missing like seeing an error on your screen.  Please pay full attention to anything that appears.

Comment: Oops!  nvidia-driver-440

Comment: I ran `nvidia-driver-440` and that's what I got https://pastebin.com/8xqJyMeY
And right after that Update-notifier popped up saying `System program problem detected` with choice of sending report or not

Comment: Ha-ha, it broke again after reboot

Comment: When you ran that fix with the `dkpg-divert`, did you remove the 390 driver after it was fixed?  Once it is gone, you should be able to install the 440 driver after that one.  I did help someone before with the `divert` answer as well.  https://askubuntu.com/a/1067214/231142

Answer (score 2):

install next version(390.129) using this ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```