# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and NVIDIA card low resolution

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, kernel

This is a Q&A for when you are using the Graphics Drivers PPA at greater than the 390 driver as well as 18.04.3 LTS.

---

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.3 and I have a NVIDIA GeForce GTX 750 Ti. My video driver currently is `nvidia-driver-440` that I installed from the [Graphics Drivers PPA](https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and I did not use the `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` for the driver.

Recently my kernel updated to `5.3.0-26-generic` and my video resolution is now stuck at 640x480.  And it appears as though my video driver is installed, but did not load with the kernel.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*NOTE: Recently after I originally posted this answer I ended up helping 2 others with similar issues, but both were using the `nvidia-driver-390`.  It appears that the 390 driver is incompatible with the 5.3.xxxx kernel and should be removed first and a newer driver be installed.*

---

The new `5.3.0-26-generic` kernel that is part of the [HWE - Hardware 
Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) does not automatically build the NVIDIA driver module into the new kernel update.  To fix this you need to get the driver version you have installed and the kernel version you are going to install it in to.

See if you are booted to the `5.3.0-26-generic` kernel by using `uname -r`:

```
$ uname -r
5.3.0-26-generic
```

If it is not installed, please install `dkms` to your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install dkms
```

Run the following command to show you the present driver and kernel:

```
dkms status
```

You should see output like the following:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 440.48.02, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver, 2.7.0, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Since the `440.48.02` driver is already installed in my last kernel version from 18.04.2 using the `5.0.0-37-generic` kernel, but the `5.3.0-26-generic` kernel is not listed that is where we need to install the driver to.

It is installed in the following format

```
sudo dkms install nameofdriver/version -k kernelversion
```

So, to install that driver into the kernel and have it activate at boot run the following line:

```
sudo dkms install nvidia/440.48.02 -k 5.3.0-26-generic
```

Or if booted to `5.3.0-26-generic` you can run it as:

```
sudo dkms install nvidia/440.48.02 -k $(uname -r)
```

You can change the above line to match any driver that needs to be installed into the kernel.  I also ran the install for my `openrazer-driver` for my keyboard.

After running that line the output of `dkms status` should now be like:

```
terrance@terrance-ubuntu:~$ dkms status
nvidia, 440.48.02, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia, 440.48.02, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver, 2.7.0, 5.0.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
openrazer-driver, 2.7.0, 5.3.0-26-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Reboot your system and your video driver should now be loaded and you should be able to obtain your full resolutions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The problem the OP most likely has is that the build of the kernel module has failed with an error because he has an older version of the nvidia driver package installed that does not work with kernel 5.3.x. E.g. xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390.

Comment: @ernstkl Both the question and answer here are mine, and no, it was not most likely the 390 driver, which I do know is incompatible after I helped 2 other people after I posted this.  I fixed my question to reflect the problem I had that others in the same boat as me that don't use the `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and are already using the graphics-drivers ppa.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have an older version of the nvidia driver package installed, like nvidia-driver-390. For this the automatic build of the kernel module fails (see files in /var/crash).

Solution: install a newer driver, e.g. nvidia-driver-435

Comment: OP needs to remove `nvidia-driver-390` first.