Lazarus dpkg-divert error
I'm having a problem after upgrading to 24.04 with the upgrade of lazarus.
The errors I obtain are these:
    workstationlinux@workstationlinux:~$ sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq lazarus-src-2.2
(Reading database ... 973636 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing lazarus-src-2.2 (2.2.6+dfsg2-2) ...
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk to /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk.orig by lazarus-src-2.2'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk to /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk.orig by lazarus-src-2.0'
dpkg: error processing package lazarus-src-2.2 (--remove):
 installed lazarus-src-2.2 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lazarus-src-2.2

And also:
workstationlinux@workstationlinux:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  lazarus-src-2.2
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gdal-data gdal-plugins libgdal34t64 libgeos-c1t64 libgeos3.12.1t64 libkysdk-applications libopencv-imgcodecs406t64 librttopo1 libspatialite8t64 libukcc3
The following packages will be upgraded:
  ukui-panel ukui-power-manager
2 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/13.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 115 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 973636 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing lazarus-src-2.2 (2.2.6+dfsg2-2) ...
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package
  when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk to /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformasp
ascaldemopkg.lpk.orig by lazarus-src-2.2'
  found 'diversion of /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldemopkg.lpk to /usr/lib/lazarus/2.0.10/examples/pascalstream/CopyAsPasPkg/copyformaspascaldem
opkg.lpk.orig by lazarus-src-2.0'
dpkg: error processing package lazarus-src-2.2 (--remove):
 installed lazarus-src-2.2 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 lazarus-src-2.2
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The solution provided in another post is not working, and I can't understand if there's something else that I can do.
Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!

sudo dpkg -P lazarus-src-2.0 does this Work?

Does this answer your question? Nvidia driver installation keeps failing, diversion issues

Thanks to both of you.
Unfortunately, sudo dpkg -P lazarus-src-2.0 works but the problem is with lazarus-src-2.2 which continues to give the same error;
I also already tried what's written here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067183/nvidia-driver-installation-keeps-failing-diversion-issues
but it's not working.

Ok,
i followed the last comment here:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1768050
and basically in /var/lib/dpkg I renamed the diversions-old file to diversion_old.old and the diversions file to diversions-old, and then created a new diversions file manually removing all the diversions for "lazarus*".
Finally with apt --fix-broken install everything works again
