# Ubuntu 18.04 Unable to use OpenCL/Cuda

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu-driver, opencl

```
 - System: Ubuntu 18.04
 - Linux Kernel Version: I tried 4.15 through 4.17
   (both custom and standard repo kernels)
 - Nvidia Driver: 396
 - Graphics Card (GPU): Nvidia GeForce 1080
 - CPU: i7-8700K (Coffeelake)
 - Cuda Version: 9.1
 - ocl-icd-libopencl1 Version: 2.2.11-1ubuntu1
 - ocl-icd-libopencl1 Provides: libopencl-1.1-1, libopencl-1.2-1,
   libopencl-2.0-1, libopencl-2.1-1, libopencl1
 - clinfo Output:

    Number of platforms                               1
      Platform Name                                   Clover    
      Platform Vendor                                 Mesa    
      Platform Version                                OpenCL 1.1 Mesa 18.1.1    
      Platform Profile                                FULL_PROFILE    
      Platform Extensions                             cl_khr_icd    
      Platform Extensions function suffix             MESA       
      Platform Name                                   Clover    
    Number of devices                                 0        
    NULL platform behavior    
      clGetPlatformInfo(NULL, CL_PLATFORM_NAME, ...)  Clover    
      clGetDeviceIDs(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, ...)   Clover

      clCreateContext(NULL, ...) [default]            No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT)  No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)  No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)  No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)  No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CUSTOM)  No devices found in platform    
      clCreateContextFromType(NULL, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL)  No devices found in platform        
    ICD loader properties    
      ICD loader Name                                 OpenCL ICD Loader    
      ICD loader Vendor                               OCL Icd free software    
      ICD loader Version                              2.2.11    
      ICD loader Profile                              OpenCL 2.1
```

I have been using OpenGL and OpenCL successfully for quite some time. However, I have not been able to use OpenCL recently. I update my system monthly. I used OpenCL successfully in May. As for June, I did not use OpenCL until this past week. I assume an update that I got in the beginning of this month is the cause (but I could be wrong). I have tried downgrading the Linux kernel (and trying various kernel versions), Nvidia drivers (390 and 396), and various graphics-related libraries without success. The output of clinfo no longer sees my Nvidia card (like it did in May).

Interestingly, OpenGL is perfectly fine. I can still use the Nvidia card for graphics rendering. The output of nvidia-smi shows my various processes running on the graphics card in graphics-mode (but no compute-mode processes).

What am I over-looking in getting OpenCL to work again?

This detail may or may not be related or provide a hint, but the output of eglinfo shows that dlopen cannot find vgem_dri.so.

Comment: I don't have the same system you have so I don't think I could write a very good answer.  I also don't like to write answers based on guesses, so I will comment here instead.  Have you tried running `sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-cuda-toolkit`?  The opencl is loading against the built in video of your CPU instead of your NVIDIA 1080 card.  I will also go ahead and  upvote this question in hopes for it being more visual for more help from people.  I did, however, write this answer based on a clean install for 18.04:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142

Comment: @Terrance , yes, I have tried reinstalling nvidia-cuda-toolkit as well as all other Nvidia and Cuda packages. However, this did not resolve the issue.

Comment: I didn't know if it would.  Your problem though is your video is defaulting to the Intel one on the CPU.  This is a little older for 16.04 but it might still work for 18.04 http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/04/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @Terrance I read the link you provided and tried the solution without success. I also tried reinstalling intel-microcode and all Optimus/Prime related packages. I also tried uninstalling such packages and reinstalling.