# Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS loses graphics card support?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

It's been a while ago, and been dreading to experiment more. Since the kernel update from `4.4.0-128.154` to `4.4.0-130.156` it seems like Ubuntu does not recognize my graphics card. Sometimes on a restart it gives me graphics, but gives me this "Gone into low graphics mode, please reconfigure or troubleshoot" and I cannot proceed to a desktop. Other times I just get a blinking cursor on a black screen and sometimes in that state I can jump to another `tty`. Most the screen will clear, give me a few lines of startup logs, then blink several times as it tries to launch the login screen (`lightdm`). After it has blinked (assuming it does stop blinking) I can go into another `tty`. However, going back to `4.4.0-128.154` and having `nvidia-384.130` installed it all runs fine (assuming I just shutdown without making changes).

With that said, when I've felt like trying to make `4.4.0-130.156` or higher work I have gone into a `tty` or `recovery mode` and tried a multitude of things I have found on the internet like `dpkg-reconfigure`, `dpkg --configure`, purged and reinstalled `nvidia` (current or specific number), going up from `384.130` to `387.26` and back again, purged and reinstalled `lightdm`, going back to `4.4.0-128.154` and setting proprietary drivers to `X.Org X server`, you name it. Each restart gives me one of the above results. And yes, I do get problems in `4.4.0-128.154` should I, say, remove `nvidia` all together.

Also, the few times when it does give me the "Low graphics mode" dialog box, whenever I try clicking reconfigure it just blinks and doesn't seem to do anything. When I choose the option to "Edit configuration file", the text-editor is blank.

This is the `Xorg.0.log` that I `cp`d over after reviewing the log from "Low graphics mode": https://pastebin.com/WtYsQ4Dm

This is the results from `glxinfo` that I ran today from a working `4.4.0-128.154` kernel and `lightdm`: https://pastebin.com/j3CXu6uc

Current Graphics Card: GeForce GTX 960/PCIe/SSE2 (GM206)

Any ideas what might be the problem here? Any other info-commands you want me to paste here?

**EDIT** The update to `4.4.0-133.139` has arrived, still the same problem. I have also been prompted to go up to 18.04 LTS, but I don't want to go there just yet and risk not getting back to the so far stable `4.4.0-128`.

**EDIT** Well, Ubuntu decided to remove the `128` kernel forcing me to use the recent, and of course NVIDIA refused to launch which meant no Desktop. I practically just gave up and decided to `do-release-upgrade` to 18.04 (`4.15.0-38`). After a night of answering `keep` or `discard` questions and rebooting, the Desktop (`lightdm`) still did not open. After some searches I saw one could get drivers from the official Nvidia site, so I purged anything `nvidia*` related, and installed `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-410.66.run`. That got me a Desktop. However, I did a test with Blender (2.79) and there was no GPU support. Installed `nvidia-modprobe` to get the CUDA, rebooted, and still Blender did not have GPU support.

Going to System Tools -> Administration -> Software Update -> Settings (once displayed) -> Additional Drivers I found 3 options: Nvidia `390`, `nouveau`, and a checked Configuration Set Manually. I assumed this was the Nvidia `410` that I installed. I decided to install `nvidia-drivers-390` on top of `410`, then purged, then `apt-get install nvidia-drivers-390 nvidia-modprobe nvidia-cuda-toolkit` all in one, rebooted, and tried Blender again. Still no GPU support.

Kinda considering to return this to the backup I have, upgrade to the `128` kernel, then disable all updates unless I get all functionality back.

Comment: Can't help you directly. But since I have the same version of Ubuntu, I'm wondering why your kernel is on the 4.4 series, whereas mine is on 4.15, and whether that might make a difference

Comment: @PaulBenson As far as I know, I think I've been updating through the 4.4 since the beginning... Well, with this new computer, I started off in 14.04 LTS, then dist-upgraded to 16.04 LTS. Also, this is a 64-bit machine (kernel x86_64).

Comment: @PaulBenson Just discovered I made a backup of the fresh install of the 14.04 on this machine. The kernel appears to be 4.2.0-37.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There was one thing that I missed because it didn't seem to work last time.

`apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and update and upgrade only just worked now.

All is well with the world again. Credit goes here: [How do I install the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit on 18.04 with Coffee Lake - is it supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030886/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-18-04-with-coffee-lake-is-it-suppo)