# Unable to install Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04

Installing Nvidia drivers and rebooting gets me stuck on Ubuntu loading up. I suspect GDM(Gnome Display Manager) might not be launching properly. One time I was stuck in this screen:

[image: Screenshot 1(top screen)]

[image: Screenshot 2(bottom screen)]

From this screen I can get to tty and purge all Nvidia drivers and reboot back in with `nouveau.modeset=0`

And, sometimes it gets me stuck on `fsck` and again I have to repeat the same process and purge all Nvidia drivers before I could get Ubuntu to boot up again.

I followed the [instructions on this site](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/) to install the Nvidia drivers (`nvidia-340` for me) and its just not working out, I've scoured the internet and surfed the deepest webpages on this issue.

I'm running an i7 with Nvidia GTX 950M, Ubuntu 18.04.1

Please send help.

Comment: You could try installing the `nvidia-driver-396` in 18.04.1  The following answer in the second half of it covers the installation of the driver:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030886/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-18-04-with-coffee-lake-is-it-suppo/1030901#1030901

Comment: Thanks a lot @Terrance you just literally saved my life. Dunno why the instructions are so messed up and convoluted everywhere. If you can copy paste your comment as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try installing the `nvidia-driver-396` in 18.04.1

The following answer in the second half of it covers the installation of the driver:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142

Or

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, as of now many of the bugs related to this issue (NVIDIA Graphics) have been fixed and the installation procedure is fairly easy. (*I would recommend you to have a fresh start, and then apply this procedure)*

> 1.**Entering Grub Boot Parameters** - This can be done by going to the grub menu at boot (press `Esc` or `Shit` at boot) here press `e`. 
>  2. **Enabling Text Mode Booting** - Here add a `3` after `quiet splash` and press `F10` to reboot using the new parameters. 
> 3. **Purge NVIDIA**- Now login to the text only mode, and purge all the NVIDIA drivers completely using the `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, and reboot. While rebooting follow step 1, here edit the parameters and add the command `nomodeset` before `qiet splash`, and press `F10`
>    to reboot the using the new parameters. 
>  4. **Installing Nvidia Drivers**- once in the system run commands in the terminal `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` now.
>
> > 1. Add the drivers repository to Ubuntu, run the commands `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt update`. 
> >     Now, do not update graphic drivers via the terminal, instead search for Software & Updates in the Ubuntu GUI. here go to the additional drivers tab. Here you will find the set of NVIDIA drivers for your system. select the `nvidia-drivers-415` i think that one is the latest. *(Make sure that you do not select or keep selection in `Using X.Org X server` - selection)*
> > 2. The installation will take a while once the installation is complete, reboot the system.
> > 3. Now it isn't necessary to add nomodeset to boot parameters, the Ubuntu Os should boot properly and without any error.
> > 4. If you have added `nomodeset` parameters to Grub, remove it in this step and keep the `quiet splash` parameter alone.*(or else nvidia driver wont load)*
> > 5. Once you have completed the login, enter the Ubuntu desktop, search for the NVIDIA Xserver application, to monitior the nvidia GPU.

Comment: I was having a hard time to make Ubuntu find my nvidia drivers. I dont know if all steps were needed in my case, but after many other trials this solution worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Something to note that took me a very long time to realize:
first:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-xxx
```

you will be asked to enter a password. during the install ( read the content carefully )
then

```
reboot
```

on start up you must enroll the mok. basically click enter and try to get to a place where you are asked for the password you entered after install. 
Only then will the driver actually work.