# Ubuntu 18.04 Boot hangs at PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I had a working 16.04 working perfectly (but no bumblebee) and then upgraded to 18.04. Gnome was very laggy so I installed Unity and lightdm but it was still laggy. So I thought something was wrong with video drivers. So I purged nvidia and installed nvidia-driver-390, but I also tried to install bumblebee.

Then I reboot and startup stops with a PKCS#7 signature not signed error. I got into recovery console and removed nvidia-driver-390, but I'm still getting that same error. Had trouble enabling networking, as it would just hang and not return to recovery menu.

Any ideas what's wrong and how I can fix it? I'm thinking about running Nvidia binary installs but my home directory was encrypted and I had to give up last night. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Have you tried disabling SecureBoot in the BIOS?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can tell SecureBoot is disabled. I think I needed to disable it when I first installed Ubuntu 16.04 last year or so.

Comment: So,  I was able to recover by going into recovery and `apt purge nvidia* && apt autoremove`. Then I installed the nvidia-driver-396 package and everything seemed to work after reboot. But then I tried  (https://github.com/timrichardson/Prime-Ubuntu-18.04) and `prime-select intel` which killed my lightdm session and hung my system, and then on reboot, ended up with the same original PKCS#7 signature not signed error.

Comment: Maybe try installing the NVIDIA drivers into 18.04 this way:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1070682/231142

Comment: Yeah I've done this again and don't seem to have issue running nvidia-driver-396. I think my issue is something with the nvidia prime switching to intel. Maybe something with nvidia drm.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error and I don't have the nvidia card or the drivers. This happened after a reboot today - 18.04 was working OK this morning.

Comment: Same here. 18.04 booting fine until just now. I did install a grub update today.