# Ubuntu 18.04 - after upgrade - Display/PKCS#7 signature error

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, display, do-release-upgrade, signature

After upgrading from 17.10 to 18.04, anytime I try and open Ubuntu I am getting the following errors (which are found in my `kern.log` as well)

```
Sep 28 15:06:12 aram-UX330UAK kernel: [   15.056052] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
----
Sep 28 15:06:12 aram-UX330UAK kernel: [   15.083938] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
----
Sep 28 15:06:12 aram-UX330UAK kernel: [   15.087645] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
----
Sep 28 15:06:12 aram-UX330UAK kernel: [   15.093293] PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key
```

In particular, PKCS#7 that seems to be a common problem and not allowing me to display anything. I don't normally use the standard Ubuntu desktop (I use xmonad) but I don't even have access to the login screen (which I assume uses the standard Ubuntu desktop)

I tried a few of the previous things that I saw:

[Ubuntu 18.04 Boot hangs at PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074957/ubuntu-18-04-boot-hangs-at-pkcs7-signature-not-signed-with-a-trusted-key)

[After upgrade ubuntu 18.04 changed from GUI to Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032838/after-upgrade-ubuntu-18-04-changed-from-gui-to-terminal)

But problems that I noticed: I don't have nvidia, so I don't know if this is a graphics problem:

```
$ lspci -v | grep VGA -A 1
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 620
```

Also double checked and everything seems to be installed. I tried doing an update/upgrade and nothing new happened. I tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` to no avail.

I do have Windows dual-booted, but I have secure boot disabled (I double and triple checked the bios) so I don't think that's an issue either.

It does give me access to a terminal afterward though and after I log in I noticed the following error:

```
Failed to connect to X Server.
Cannot open display 'default display'
```

So it seems like a display issue, but no idea how to procede. I tried reinstalling xmonad to no avail.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix this or what needs to be done so that I get access to things?

### --- EDIT ---

Here's my Xorg log as asked for:

```
[ 12435.612] 
X.Org X Server 1.19.6
Release Date: 2017-12-20
[ 12435.612] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[ 12435.612] Build Operating System: Linux 4.4.0-119-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
[ 12435.612] Current Operating System: Linux aram-UX330UAK 4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 12:36:29 UTC 2018 x86_64
[ 12435.612] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-46-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=6919df57-2080-4508-82b7-0ccb1e067b6a ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[ 12435.613] Build Date: 13 April 2018  08:07:36PM
[ 12435.613] xorg-server 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[ 12435.613] Current version of pixman: 0.34.0
[ 12435.613]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[ 12435.613] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 12435.613] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Fri Sep 28 14:44:15 2018
[ 12435.613] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[ 12435.614] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[ 12435.614] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[ 12435.614] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[ 12435.614] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[ 12435.614] (==) No device specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using the first device section listed.
[ 12435.614] (**) |   |-->Device "card0"
[ 12435.614] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[ 12435.614] (==) Automatically adding devices
[ 12435.614] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[ 12435.614] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[ 12435.614] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[ 12435.614] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[ 12435.614] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 12435.614]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12435.615] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 12435.615]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12435.615] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 12435.615]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12435.615] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 12435.615]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12435.615] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 12435.615]    Entry deleted from font path.
[ 12435.615] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[ 12435.615] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[ 12435.615] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[ 12435.615] (II) Loader magic: 0x556a504d8020
[ 12435.615] (II) Module ABI versions:
[ 12435.615]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[ 12435.615]    X.Org Video Driver: 23.0
[ 12435.615]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[ 12435.615]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[ 12435.616] (++) using VT number 7

[ 12435.616] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[ 12435.617] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[ 12435.626] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:5916:1043:1520 rev 2, Mem @ 0xee000000/16777216, 0xd0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[ 12435.626] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 12435.627] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 12435.628] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12435.628]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 1.0.0
[ 12435.628]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[ 12435.628] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[ 12435.629] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[ 12435.629] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12435.629]    compiled for 1.19.5, module version = 2.99.917
[ 12435.629]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[ 12435.629]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 23.0
[ 12435.629] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[ 12435.630] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[ 12435.630] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[ 12435.630] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[ 12435.630] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20170619
[ 12435.630] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[ 12435.630] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[ 12435.649] (--) intel(0): Integrated Graphics Chipset: Intel(R) HD Graphics 620
[ 12435.649] (--) intel(0): CPU: x86-64, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, avx, avx2; using a maximum of 2 threads
[ 12435.649] (II) intel(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[ 12435.649] (==) intel(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[ 12435.649] (==) intel(0): RGB weight 888
[ 12435.649] (==) intel(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[ 12435.649] (**) intel(0): Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Output eDP1 has no monitor section
[ 12435.650] (**) intel(0): Found backlight control interface intel_backlight (type 'raw') for output eDP1
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Enabled output eDP1
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Output HDMI1 has no monitor section
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Enabled output HDMI1
[ 12435.650] (--) intel(0): Using a maximum size of 256x256 for hardware cursors
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Output VIRTUAL1 has no monitor section
[ 12435.650] (II) intel(0): Enabled output VIRTUAL1
[ 12435.650] (--) intel(0): Output eDP1 using initial mode 1920x1080 on pipe 0
[ 12435.651] (==) intel(0): TearFree enabled
[ 12435.651] (==) intel(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[ 12435.651] (==) intel(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[ 12435.651] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[ 12435.651] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[ 12435.651] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[ 12435.651] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[ 12435.651] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[ 12435.651] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[ 12435.651] (II) Loading sub module "present"
[ 12435.651] (II) LoadModule: "present"
[ 12435.651] (II) Module "present" already built-in
[ 12435.651] (==) Depth 24 pixmap format is 32 bpp
[ 12435.651] (II) intel(0): SNA initialized with Kabylake (gen9) backend
[ 12435.651] (==) intel(0): Backing store enabled
[ 12435.651] (==) intel(0): Silken mouse enabled
[ 12435.651] (II) intel(0): HW Cursor enabled
[ 12435.651] (II) intel(0): RandR 1.2 enabled, ignore the following RandR disabled message.
[ 12435.652] (==) intel(0): DPMS enabled
[ 12435.652] (==) intel(0): Display hotplug detection enabled
[ 12435.652] (II) intel(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
[ 12435.652] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   DRI driver: i965
[ 12435.652] (II) intel(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: va_gl
[ 12435.652] (II) intel(0): direct rendering: DRI2 enabled
[ 12435.652] (II) intel(0): hardware support for Present enabled
[ 12435.652] (--) RandR disabled
[ 12435.657] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_profile
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_create_context_es{,2}_profile
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_INTEL_swap_event
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_EXT_fbconfig_packed_float
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap backed by buffer objects
[ 12435.674] (II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_create_context_robustness
[ 12435.675] (II) AIGLX: Loaded and initialized i965
[ 12435.675] (II) GLX: Initialized DRI2 GL provider for screen 0
[ 12435.679] (II) intel(0): switch to mode 1920x1080@60.0 on eDP1 using pipe 0, position (0, 0), rotation normal, reflection none
[ 12435.689] (II) intel(0): Setting screen physical size to 508 x 285
[ 12435.728] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event3)
[ 12435.728] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.728] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[ 12435.729] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[ 12435.731] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12435.731]    compiled for 1.19.6, module version = 0.27.1
[ 12435.731]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 12435.731]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[ 12435.731] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 12435.731] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 12435.731] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[ 12435.732] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.732] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.732] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.732] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[ 12435.752] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3"
[ 12435.752] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[ 12435.752] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12435.752] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12435.752] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12435.769] (II) event3  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.769] (II) event3  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.769] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus Wireless Radio Control (/dev/input/event6)
[ 12435.769] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.769] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus Wireless Radio Control'
[ 12435.770] (**) Asus Wireless Radio Control: always reports core events
[ 12435.770] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[ 12435.770] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.770] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.770] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.770] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device removed
[ 12435.824] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ATK4002:00/input/input6/event6"
[ 12435.824] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus Wireless Radio Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[ 12435.824] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12435.824] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12435.824] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12435.824] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.824] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.824] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event5)
[ 12435.825] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.825] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[ 12435.825] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[ 12435.825] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[ 12435.825] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.825] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.825] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.825] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
[ 12435.876] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input5/event5"
[ 12435.876] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[ 12435.876] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12435.876] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12435.876] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12435.878] (II) event5  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.878] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.879] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Lid Switch (/dev/input/event0)
[ 12435.879] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12435.879] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12435.881] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[ 12435.881] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.881] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[ 12435.882] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[ 12435.882] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[ 12435.882] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.883] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.883] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.883] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[ 12435.916] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input2/event2"
[ 12435.916] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[ 12435.916] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12435.916] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12435.916] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12435.917] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.917] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.919] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event1)
[ 12435.919] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.919] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[ 12435.919] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[ 12435.919] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[ 12435.919] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.920] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.920] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.920] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[ 12435.972] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1"
[ 12435.972] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[ 12435.972] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12435.972] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12435.972] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12435.973] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.973] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.975] (II) config/udev: Adding input device USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD (/dev/input/event15)
[ 12435.975] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12435.975] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD'
[ 12435.975] (**) USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: always reports core events
[ 12435.975] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event15"
[ 12435.975] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12435.976] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12435.976] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard
[ 12435.976] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device removed
[ 12436.024] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input16/event15"
[ 12436.024] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[ 12436.024] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12436.024] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12436.024] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12436.025] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12436.025] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device is a keyboard
[ 12436.027] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad (/dev/input/event8)
[ 12436.027] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "libinput touchpad catchall"
[ 12436.027] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "touchpad catchall"
[ 12436.027] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: Applying InputClass "Default clickpad buttons"
[ 12436.027] (II) LoadModule: "synaptics"
[ 12436.027] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/synaptics_drv.so
[ 12436.027] (II) Module synaptics: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[ 12436.027]    compiled for 1.19.3, module version = 1.9.0
[ 12436.027]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[ 12436.027]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[ 12436.027] (II) Using input driver 'synaptics' for 'ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad'
[ 12436.027] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: always reports core events
[ 12436.027] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event8"
[ 12436.065] (II) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: found clickpad property
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: x-axis range 0 - 3208 (res 31)
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: y-axis range 0 - 2206 (res 32)
[ 12436.065] (II) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: device does not report pressure, will use touch data.
[ 12436.065] (II) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: device does not report finger width.
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: buttons: left double triple
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: Vendor 0x4f3 Product 0x3028
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: invalid pressure range.  defaulting to 0 - 255
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: invalid finger width range.  defaulting to 0 - 15
[ 12436.065] (**) Option "SoftButtonAreas" "50% 0 82% 0 0 0 0 0"
[ 12436.065] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: touchpad found
[ 12436.065] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: always reports core events
[ 12436.096] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-5/i2c-ELAN1300:00/0018:04F3:3028.0001/input/input9/event8"
[ 12436.096] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad" (type: TOUCHPAD, id 12)
[ 12436.096] (**) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) MinSpeed is now constant deceleration 2.5
[ 12436.096] (**) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) MaxSpeed is now 1.75
[ 12436.096] (**) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) AccelFactor is now 0.051
[ 12436.097] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[ 12436.097] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration profile 1
[ 12436.097] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[ 12436.097] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[ 12436.097] (--) synaptics: ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: touchpad found
[ 12436.099] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad (/dev/input/mouse0)
[ 12436.099] (**) ELAN1300:00 04F3:3028 Touchpad: Ignoring device from InputClass "touchpad ignore duplicates"
[ 12436.099] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Headphone (/dev/input/event9)
[ 12436.100] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.100] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.100] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event10)
[ 12436.100] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.100] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.101] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event11)
[ 12436.101] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.101] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.102] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event12)
[ 12436.102] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.102] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.102] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event13)
[ 12436.102] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.102] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.103] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10 (/dev/input/event14)
[ 12436.103] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[ 12436.103] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[ 12436.104] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Asus WMI hotkeys (/dev/input/event7)
[ 12436.104] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12436.104] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Asus WMI hotkeys'
[ 12436.104] (**) Asus WMI hotkeys: always reports core events
[ 12436.104] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[ 12436.104] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12436.105] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12436.105] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[ 12436.105] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[ 12436.148] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input7/event7"
[ 12436.148] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Asus WMI hotkeys" (type: KEYBOARD, id 13)
[ 12436.148] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12436.148] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12436.148] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12436.149] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12436.149] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device is a keyboard
[ 12436.150] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event4)
[ 12436.150] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[ 12436.150] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[ 12436.150] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[ 12436.150] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[ 12436.150] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[ 12436.151] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12436.151] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[ 12436.151] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[ 12436.188] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4"
[ 12436.188] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 14)
[ 12436.188] (**) Option "xkb_model" "asus_laptop"
[ 12436.188] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[ 12436.188] (**) Option "xkb_options" "lv3:menu_switch,compose:rctrl"
[ 12436.189] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[ 12436.189] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[ 12436.223] (II) event3  - Power Button: device removed
[ 12436.268] (II) event6  - Asus Wireless Radio Control: device removed
[ 12436.308] (II) event5  - Video Bus: device removed
[ 12436.348] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[ 12436.388] (II) event1  - Sleep Button: device removed
[ 12436.436] (II) event15 - USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam: USB2.0 HD: device removed
[ 12436.516] (II) event7  - Asus WMI hotkeys: device removed
[ 12436.556] (II) event4  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[ 12436.588] (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "synaptics"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.668] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.669] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[ 12436.673] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: What do you see in `/var/log/Xorg.log` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` ?

Comment: Added the Xorg log. A lot of it seems like keyboard things so I'm not really noticing anything on display really .-.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding out it was because gdm3 was not loading. I followed this: 
[gdm3 doesn't start in ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050672/gdm3-doesnt-start-in-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1)
And it ended up starting to work after two restarts.