# Ubuntu 18.04 weird behaviour of filesystem at boot

Tags: boot, 18.04

I am on ubuntu 18.04, since two days when I boot or reboot, I have a message that basically says `Checking file system (xx%)` the percentage starts at 43.59 and goes up to 48% then the screen become : 
[image]

When pressing enter, I am logged as root user. If I do :

```
$ mount -a
$ exit
```

Then everything is fine, the screen become the usual logging GUI screen asking me for my credentials. 
I saw a lot of message about `PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key` but I am unsure if it is related to my issue.

the `journalctl -xb` command output :

```
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x8e, date = 2018-03-24
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: Linux version 4.19.2-041902-generic (kernel@kathleen) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-9ubuntu1)) #201811132032 SMP Tue Nov 13 20:34:19 UTC 2018
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.2-041902-generic root=UUID=15155a74-2b7f-456c-805d-7ccebd469548 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: KERNEL supported cpus:
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel:   Intel GenuineIntel
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel:   AMD AuthenticAMD
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel:   Centaur CentaurHauls
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[3]:  832, xstate_sizes[3]:   64
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: xstate_offset[4]:  896, xstate_sizes[4]:   64
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x1f, context size is 960 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x0000000000057fff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000058000-0x0000000000058fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000059000-0x000000000009dfff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009e000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000062d3efff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000062d3f000-0x0000000062d3ffff] ACPI NVS
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000062d40000-0x0000000062d40fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000062d41000-0x000000007a48dfff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a48e000-0x000000007a68dfff] type 20
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007a68e000-0x000000007ae7dfff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ae7e000-0x000000007ce7dfff] ACPI NVS
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ce7e000-0x000000007cefdfff] ACPI data
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007cefe000-0x000000007cefefff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000007ceff000-0x000000007fffffff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000fe7fffff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000fec00fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed00000-0x00000000fed00fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed10000-0x00000000fed19fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fed84000-0x00000000fed84fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fee00000-0x00000000fee00fff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ffa00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000027effffff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: efi: EFI v2.50 by INSYDE Corp.
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: efi:  ACPI 2.0=0x7cefd014  SMBIOS=0x7a702000  SMBIOS 3.0=0x7a700000  ESRT=0x7a6fe558  MEMATTR=0x6adf9018 
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: DMI: LENOVO 80WK/LNVNB161216, BIOS 4KCN40WW 10/17/2017
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: tsc: Detected 2500.000 MHz processor
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: tsc: Detected 2496.000 MHz TSC
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: last_pfn = 0x27f000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: MTRR default type: write-back
nov. 14 17:44:22 louis-pc kernel: MTRR fixed ranges enabled:
```

not sure if there is any relevant informations sadly.

EDIT : Is there any way to automatically run `mount -a` at boot time ?

Comment: There are a number of related questions, if you search for "PKCS#7 signature not signed with a trusted key".  This is related to a hardware issue, apparently, and there are a couple of different fixes:  [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455189/pkcs7-signature-not-signed-with-a-trusted-key](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455189/pkcs7-signature-not-signed-with-a-trusted-key) or [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079324/ubutnu-18-04-after-upgrade-display-pkcs7-signature-error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079324/ubutnu-18-04-after-upgrade-display-pkcs7-signature-error)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. I am unsure if this is related to my issue tho. But I'll let you know

Comment: Turn off **Secure Boot** in your BIOS. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Secure boot is already disabled