# Video/Graphic driver is broke

Tags: boot, drivers

I am running ubuntu 18.10 on a Acer Aspire One, D255E. It has been working fine, but now every time I try to boot up it goes to a black screen and nothing else. Recovery mode doesn't work either. I've gotten in once, using nomodeset, but I don't know how to fix the issue after that. Truthfully, I'm new at using linux. I thinks it's my video driver, but I don't know how to fix it. Please Help!

EDIT: I managed to get in, but I still have no idea how to fix the driver.

Comment: welcome to askUbuntu! have you tried booting with nomodeset then using "Software & Updates" -> "Additional Drivers" to see what's available? what video card are you using?

Comment: When using additional drivers nothing comes up. As far as I know I'm using a Atom Processor D4xx/D5xx/N4xx/N5xx Integrated Graphics Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel update caused same for me. I posted long note here two days ago. My advice is run the older kernel

[kernel 4.18.0.11.12 trouble](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096250/kernel-4-18-0-11-12-trouble)