# get logged off on resume from suspend Nvidia 390 drivers 2nd monitor (18.10)

Tags: suspend, external-monitor, resume

This is not a problem using only built in laptop screen however when using Nvidia 390 drivers I attach an external monitor and choose

```
Setting->Display->Single Display
```

then choose the external monitor to be the only active screen -> then when I suspend upon resume I have gotten logged off which is mentioned in  `/var/log/auth.log`

this issue is repeatable across multiple laptops with Nvidia cards ... issue is only when using nvidia drivers, nouveau drivers are OK no issue

Any ideas/suggestions ?

Here is a clip from `/var/log/auth.log` look closely at messages just after `Lid opened`

Looks like it could be  gnome-shell ? I booked a ticket https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1806165

```
Nov 30 21:17:01 nuem CRON[17437]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 30 21:17:01 nuem CRON[17437]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Nov 30 21:20:18 nuem gnome-keyring-daemon[3057]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/863, but it's already registered
Nov 30 21:20:19 nuem gnome-keyring-daemon[3057]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/862, but it's already registered
Nov 30 21:40:36 nuem gnome-keyring-daemon[3057]: asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered
Nov 30 21:40:39 nuem gnome-keyring-daemon[3057]: message repeated 2 times: [ asked to register item /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login/1, but it's already registered]
Nov 30 21:49:25 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Lid closed.
Nov 30 21:49:29 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Lid opened.
Nov 30 21:49:51 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Nov 30 21:49:52 nuem polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.376, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov 30 21:49:52 nuem gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session closed for user upha
Nov 30 21:49:52 nuem dbus-daemon[507]: [system] Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.2100" (uid=1000 pid=31115 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (bus)
Nov 30 21:49:52 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Session 2 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov 30 21:49:53 nuem gdm-launch-environment]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 30 21:49:53 nuem systemd-logind[523]: New session c2 of user gdm.
Nov 30 21:49:53 nuem systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user gdm by (uid=0)
Nov 30 21:49:55 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Removed session 2.
Nov 30 21:49:56 nuem systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session closed for user upha
Nov 30 21:49:57 nuem polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.2108 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Nov 30 21:50:07 nuem gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user upha by (uid=0)
Nov 30 21:50:07 nuem systemd-logind[523]: New session 37 of user upha.
Nov 30 21:50:07 nuem systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user upha by (uid=0)
Nov 30 21:50:17 nuem polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:37 (system bus name :1.2405 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Nov 30 21:50:19 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Session c2 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov 30 21:50:19 nuem polkitd(authority=local): Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-session:c2 (system bus name :1.2108, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Nov 30 21:50:19 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Removed session c2.
Nov 30 21:52:50 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Nov 30 21:52:59 nuem gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Nov 30 21:53:42 nuem systemd-logind[523]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
Nov 30 21:53:50 nuem gdm-password]: gkr-pam: unlocked login keyring
Nov 30 22:17:02 nuem CRON[6950]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Nov 30 22:17:02 nuem CRON[6950]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

I installed the Nvidia drivers by picking from list on Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers ... This scenario is not an issue on 16.04

Answer (score 0):

I found a suggested answer for this problem with newer kernels and gdm, if that is your greeter.  See post here:

[kernel 4.18.0.11.12 trouble: Video black screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1096250/kernel-4-18-0-11-12-trouble-video-black-screen)

Make those inserts in /etc/default/grub and run `sudo update-grub`.

Claim in Nvidia forum is that there's a bug in the kernel that requires this.

1 See my thread:

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044730/linux/x-displays-in-a-small-section-of-screen-something-in-my-grub-setup-wrong-/

2 Here is the one about failing to recover from suspend

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044633/?comment=5300281

I do note that if you use the lightdm display manager, none of this is a problem. Except for stubbornness in wanting to find out why gdm was causing trouble, I have no good reason to try so hard to make it work.  And it does work, whether or not with X11 or Wayland (you choose in /etc/gdm/custom.conf).