# Installing Nvidia Drivers / Power Use bug

Tags: drivers, nvidia

A few months back I installed Ubuntu for the first time on a new laptop and started getting accustomed to it. After doing the initial setup and installing nvidia drivers for my dedicated gpu I encountered a bug that would cause the drivers to not unload properly once prime-select was switched to intel.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1778011

Now as I'm looking at this, and correct me if I'm wrong, the bug seems to be resolved.

Does that mean that I have to install nvidia-390 and that will contain the bugfix or do I need to install a different driver?

Nvidia-396 which seems to be the latest stable driver returns a not found when trying to install from terminal.

Using ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Here's the output of `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1d12
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )
           drivers: modesetting (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@59.98hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
           version: 4.5 Mesa 18.0.5
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1070682/231142 for installing the 396 driver into Ubuntu.  If you are using 18.04, the driver is listed there in the link.  If you are using 16.04 the driver name would be `nvidia-396`

Comment: I tried doing that, but I get these errors back, not sure what they mean https://textuploader.com/dvmwp

Comment: It means that the PPA is not setup properly.  What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm on 18.04.01, everything is up to date

Comment: Please try redoing the PPA.  Something is not set up right.  I have 18.04.1 and the drivers were easily installed through that link I posted.  I forgot to ask, what video card do you have?

Comment: I tried removing the ppa from "Software and Updates" and then adding it again but the problem is the same. I have a Geforce 940MX, however for some reason the model doesn't appear under the "Additional Drivers" tab, I'm not sure if that's normal. https://i.imgur.com/hHcD5ft.png

Comment: From my understanding it should be showing the card at the top.  Try installing `inxi`, `sudo apt install inxi` then run `inxi -G` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Added to the OP

Comment: Hmmm, that is interesting because normally NVIDIA shows up with the correct name.  Have you tried booting to a LiveCD/DVD and try there?  Maybe like an older 16.04 disc.  Might need to eliminate software of 18.04 having problems with it.  I am truly running out of ideas here.

Comment: I might just end up reinstalling everything, I probably messed this up quite a lot by testing out things I shouldn't have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a fix.

While having `nvidia-390` installed I couldn't install `nvidia-driver-396` as the terminal would just spit out errors that I couldn't fix.

The newest drivers refused to download and install until the point where I ran

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-390
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

(I also ran `sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*` since I wasn't sure if that had installed anything related to nvidia)

Once that was done I ran

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-396
```

And it worked perfectly. I still can't see the name of my video card in Ubuntu itself, but everything seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> the bug seems to be resolved.

It looks as though it was resolved but not yet released:

*"I hope we can finally get ubuntu-drivers-common into bionic-proposed now"*

You can try out the version of nvidia-390 he uploaded to the PPA.

Comment: How would I install the version he uploaded to the ppa?

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:albertomilone/hybridgraphics