# Bumblebee: module 'nvidia-390' not found

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I managed to get Bumblebee to run some time ago, but after an update it just completely stopped. I'm trying to set it up again but I can't get past this error

```
[ 3270.586218] [ERROR]Module 'nvidia-390' is not found.
```

After googling I found [this](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/Troubleshooting#bumblebeed-module-nvidia-is-not-found), which looks my exact problem. After running `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name 'nvidia*.ko*'` I receive

```
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/kernel/drivers/video/fbdev/nvidia/nvidiafb.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-modeset.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-uvm.ko
/lib/modules/4.15.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia-drm.ko
```

None of these look like what I need, which means I must be missing the kernel headers.

Where do I find these? Is there a guide I can follow that will tell me how to install them?

Using Ubuntu 18.04.01 LTS

Comment: I believe all you have to run is `sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` to install the headers.

Comment: I tried running that and the terminal tells me that the latest generic headers are already installed. Bumblebee still doesn't work however

Comment: You should probably work on one question at a time right now since they both work with your drivers.  You should probably close this or the other.  Here it is showing the kernel modules are loaded, so the headers are not the issue.  The issue might lie in what version of Ubuntu you are running because of driver differences between them.  Neither one of you questions you have not put what version of Ubuntu you are using and that is vitally important.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise I should mention it. I'd rather keep both questions open though since I do want a response to both.

Comment: The driver in Ubuntu 18.04.1 should be `nvidia-driver-396`  See https://askubuntu.com/a/1070682/231142  Once with the proper driver, it might solve both issues.