# Can't change to NVIDIA drivers Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, xorg

I have installed nvidia-driver-396, however when I try to select that driver in the driver manager GUI and press Apply it simply refreshes the list a defaults back to the Nouveau driver (which isn't loaded because it's actually blacklisted).

Has anyone experienced this? If so; how can I load the nvidia-driver-396 driver?

Comment: Maybe try this way:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1070682/231142  But first run a removal of the existing drivers by doing `sudo apt remove nvidia-*`