# What's the correct Nvidia driver for my card+system?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm attempting to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers for my card:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA               
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96 [GeForce 9500 GT] (rev a1)
```

on my system:

```
$ lsb_release -a -u
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

I've followed the steps outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070630/unable-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-1):

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

but the command

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-
```

shows several available versions of the driver:

```
nvidia-driver-390  nvidia-driver-396  nvidia-driver-410  nvidia-driver-415  nvidia-driver-418
```

I've seen the `396` version used several times, but intuitively I would install the latest version. How do I know which one I should install?

Comment: For that old card choose the latest legacy driver version.

Comment: Which one would that be @GabrielaGarcia?

Comment: According to Nvidia that should be 340. If not available in the official repos or at a PPA better not to install anything else and just use the open-source `nouveau`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Geforce 9600 GT owner I can write the following.

I'm using it with [nvidia-340](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=nvidia-340&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) driver on my 16.04 LTS, it still exists for all current releases. It is recommended on [Nvidia Drivers site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/135161/en-us).

The driver PPA are not needed. So you may remove the PPA with

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

and install `nvidia-340`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

Comment: Thanks Norbert, I Installed the 340 drivers. Sadly now I'm getting [this bug](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/nvidia-driver-makes-the-screen-pale-colours-washed-out.2710650/) and I might have to go back to `nouveau`.

Comment: Fixed it! Had to change the color range from `Full` to `Limited` for some reason.

Comment: Nice to hear, that you have fixed the issue!