# Unable to install NVidia graphics drivers for Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, gnome, 64-bit, intel

I followed the instructions on [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070630/unable-to-install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-1/1070682) to attempt to install NVidia drivers (nvidia-driver-396) on my ASUS GL-553VD, with NVidia GTX 1050. After building was complete, these error messages popped up.

nvidia:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 396.54 for nvidia.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.15.0-48-generic (430.09).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 396.54 for nvidia-modeset.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.15.0-48-generic (430.09).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 396.54 for nvidia-drm.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.15.0-48-generic (430.09).
You may override by specifying --force.

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-48-generic/updates/dkms/

Then, the installation finished. However, upon reboot, through multiple checks (Settings-Details-About, lsmod, nvidia-settings, nvidia-smi) I determined that intel integrated graphics was still being used. Since I have made multiple attempts to install various drivers, as well as attempted to install through the run file on the [official site](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/137211/en-us), I suspect that the failure could be because of interference. None of my attempts to install drivers have been successful. However, installing drivers has helped in that while before I could only see a black screen unless I booted through secure mode, now I can use Ubuntu properly except for my graphics card. How do I install drivers and enable my graphics card?

Comment: Why are you trying to install an older version than you already have?

Comment: The same issue popped up with the next gen drivers. I tried installing older drivers to check if it was a compatibility issue.

Comment: You'll end up creating a mess that will be hard to untangle. Suggestions: 1. Purge all Nvidia drivers you have mixed up already with `sudo apt purge nvidia*`. 2. Knowing that the recommended version for your card is now 418 (maybe not available in 18.04 repositories), first add the graphics drivers PPA. 3. Simply open Additional Drivers and select and apply 418 (or 430), reboot. Things NOT to do: Mixing different versions without purging; installing from the Nvidia downloads.

Comment: I did use purge before installing a new driver everytime, but those drivers were still listed under the additional drivers tab in Software & Updates. Couldn't figure out how to remove them completely

Comment: The drivers versions are listed there because they are available in one or other software source. It doesn't mean any is installed and they're not supposed to be removed from there.