# "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver"

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu-driver

Work for less than a year with GTX1080ti. Suddenly, after a regular sudo update, it stopped working.

nvidia-smi results in

"NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running."

Tried this [How do I install the NVIDIA CUDA toolkit on 18.04 with Coffee Lake - is it supported?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030886/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-cuda-toolkit-on-18-04-with-coffee-lake-is-it-suppo)  and ran **clinfo** but got

Number of platforms                               0

After uninstalling and installing nvidia driver (430) several times, tryed many possible solutions, still gets the same error. Interesting, when running **inxi** I got the next output. 
[inxi output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAHT3.png)

As you can see, NVIDIA card is not detected, but I got a faulty reading about the gpu temperature (if run before nvidia driver installation, no gpu temp is seen). Any thought? Is it my card broken, or just a driver conflict issue?

Comment: If you boot with a previous kernel (grub menu, advanced options), does that fix the problem?

Comment: I'm on a server, can I access advanced options from terminal?

Comment: You need to reinstall the driver for current kernel. Now you are using `i915` driver (according to inxi).

Comment: When you boot your server you get the grub menu, from it select "Advanced Options" and from that menu select the version prior to 4.15.0-64.