# Installing nvidia driver is overwriting cuda toolkit version on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, software-installation, cuda, tensorflow

Installing nvidia drivers and cuda toolkit versions that are compatible with tensorflow is proving to be as enjoyable as ingrown toenail surgery.

I specifically need **cuda toolkit 10.0** because tensorflow 1.14 only supports this version. If I could use 10.1 or 10.2, I would have solved this weeks ago.

I have followed numerous posts [[1]](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu)[[2]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/440840/how-to-unload-kernel-module-nvidia-drm)[[3]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054954/how-to-install-nvidia-driver-in-ubuntu-18-04)[[4]](https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Install-CUDA-10-together-with-9-2-on-Ubuntu-18-04-with-support-for-NVIDIA-20XX-Turing-GPUs-1236/)[[5]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely#) to try and uninstall all existing cuda and nvidia software and start again from scratch, but nothing works; sometimes I get `Unmet Dependancies` errors and when I try to install the dependancies, I get new errors until I am 5 dependancies down a rabbit hole.

The latest I have tried is to manually download cuda 10.0 from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.0-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=runfilelocal) and run the .sh file (runfile (local)). I select `Y` for all the prompts except for installing the samples. This seems to work fine; I see cuda 10.0 is installed under `/usr/local/`. Then I install the nivida drivers using

`$ sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends nvidia-driver-430`

here is where the problems start. I reboot the computer, run `nividia-smi` and find that while the driver is installed correctly (version 430.50), the toolkit is **10.1**!!! It seems that installing the driver is overwriting the cuda toolkit version? `cuda-10.0` is still located under `/usr/local/` and if I run `/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc --version` or `cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` I see that both give version 10.0. I don't understand how the nvidia driver is using (or at least displaying) cuda version 10.1.

Is there some way I can install cuda toolkit version 10.0 and some nvidia driver (>=410.x) so that tensorflow will work with my GPU?