# When will CUDA support ubuntu 18.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, 18.10, unsupported-packages

I need to use CUDA for work and have upgraded Ubuntu without checking (my bad) whether CUDA supports Ubuntu 18.10, turns out [it doesn't](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html).

The last supported version is Ubuntu 18.04.5.
When do you think CUDA will support Ubuntu 18.10 ? And if it'll take a while, what would be the best way to downgrade my version to 18.04 ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 is imaginary right now. While it is likely to happen, it won't be started for years. Downgrading is possible, but not tested or supported - the recommended method is to backup your data and clean-install the earlier release of Ubuntu.

Comment: An earlier CUDA version may work fine without needing special packages or non-Ubuntu Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have successfully installed CUDA 10.0 on Kubuntu 18.10. You need the runfile and gcc version 6.

1. Go to the [CUDA download site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone). Click on Linux -> x86_64 -> Ubuntu -> 18.04 (although we have 18.10) -> runfile (local).
2. Open a new terminal environment with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> (I think on Ubuntu the default windows environment is on <kbd>F7</kbd>, while in Kubuntu is on <kbd>F1</kbd>) and login as root.
3. Stop the display manager in order to stop the X server and install the drivers successfully. For me, on Kubuntu 18.10 that was achieved with:
   `service sddm stop`
   To find out your display manager, you can try running
   `pgrep -l dm`
4. Run the CUDA installer with the override option:
   `./cuda_10.0.130_410.48_linux --override`
   The override option will ignore the compiler version check. CUDA requires gcc version 6, but the installation goes fine with gcc version 8 too. The override option allow us to proceed using a later version of the compiler. Install the drivers, the toolkit and the samples too.
5. Restart the desktop manager
   `service sddm start`
   and switch again to the desktop environment.
6. Add the CUDA include directory and the CUDA library directory to your `.bashrc` file. I have installed CUDA under `/usr/local/cuda-10.0`, so I had to add
   `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64/`
7. Go to the samples directory and compile them. This time gcc version 6 is required. Install it
   `sudo apt-get install g++-6`
   and compile the samples using g++ version 6 as the compiler
   `make HOST_COMPILER=g++-6`

Done!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend to try it even if it's not supported before trying to downgrade. CUDA also worked on 18.04 before it was supported and there is a CUDA-package in the [Cosmic sources](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cosmic/nvidia-cuda-toolkit).

Use the installation guide provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036265/853882) by eromod:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

reboot

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6

nvcc --version
```

Comment: when I do `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` it installs gcc-7.  Then I cannot install the cuda toolkit properly I think.

Comment: You can have different gcc versions at once. When I posted this, cuda needed gcc6, they may have upgraded since.

Comment: I gave up and just use Conda envs now with `pip install tensorflow-gpu`

Answer (score 2):

I cannot tell when it will be supported, but for the moment, from current experience, cuda is not supported in ubuntu 18.10 as it uses xserver abi 24 while the nvidia drivers still only support abi 23

On the other hand, having upgraded without checking for issues and needing an interim solution, you can add the bionic main repository to your sources.list

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

and downgrade the xserver packages (xserver-xorg-core and xserver-xorg-video-*)

I'm using cuda 10 from NVidia's repository at

```
deb http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64 /
```