# Can not install Nvidia drivers in Kubuntu 18.04/18.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kubuntu

For some reason, I have been unable to properly install Nvidia drivers on my laptop on both Kubuntu 18.04 and 18.10. Kubuntu notifies me that I should install proprietary drivers as soon as I boot into it, but going to the driver section of the settings, I have been unable to install any of the Nvidia packages that are shown there, even if I try the option that is marked as recommended.
Trying to install it on the first time shows Kubuntu as trying to install the driver, and then the drivers list simply refreshes, showing that the system is on the nouveau driver. Any further attempts to select one of the nvidia drivers and to lick apply simply results in the list refreshing back on nouveau. And, whenever the next reboot after this failed installation attempt happens, Kubuntu doesn't boot properly anymore. It boots, shows the Kubuntu logo, and then it remains black.

I've met the exact same problem on both 18.04 and 18.10. I saw some Reddit comments mentioning that this is a known issue, something on Nvidia's side I think, but I have not been able to find any details, and I'm not sure what to do.

I have an ASUS X550LB laptop, with a Intel Core i7 4500U, and Nvidia GT 740M.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problems when I tried to install die Nvidia drivers in order to install CUDA. The Driver-List provided by Plasma (where you switch between nouveau and proprietary) didn't work either.

What did work for me (Kubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 18.04 with additional KDE) was this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

([Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036265/853882))

You may have to remove your manually installed drivers before doing this.

Comment: Well, I'll try this as soon as I will reinstall Kubuntu. I was unable to boot into it properly like I said, so I'm preparing a usb with it as I'm posting this. I will try your solution as soon as I do reinstall it.

Comment: Try shutting it down, removing your GPU and reboot with a Display connected to a slot directly on your Motherboard. You probably can avoid a reinstall of the system.

Comment: I'm unfortunately using it on a laptop, so I can't do that I'm afraid. Thanks for the advice, but I'll just reinstall it - I didn't have any personal data on the laptop anyway since I'm still in the process of trying to find a single Ubuntu flavor to settle on.

Comment: Yeah, your suggestion works on 18.04, but I'm still unable to install any sort of Nvidia drives on 18.10.
Edit: Is there a way to report this issue to the developers?