# How do I install Cuda on Ubuntu 18.04 --

Tags: 18.04, cuda

***Note: Last question did not work on my system*** [How do I Install CUDA on Ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028830/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04)

I installed the CUDA toolkit on Ubuntu 18.04, but the installation does not appear complete. **How can I install CUDA properly on Ubuntu 18.04?**

I followed the advice on a prior question and have *nvcc* installed.

When I run *nvcc -V*, I have *CUDA compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85*.

Now I am searching for the *bin* directory to test the installation. See Section 7.0: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions

The only two *cuda* folders I find with *locate* are under the *anaconda3* directory. Neither of these have a *bin* folder.

Comment: If you type "which nvcc" you get the location in which it is installed.  That is the bin you are looking for, e.g  which nvcc  outputs  /usr/local/vm/cuda-8.0/bin/nvcc on my system.

Comment: nvcc was not under the cuda install. It was by itself. I have since installed CUDA, but it ruined my graphics device driver. Still working on a proper install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I suggest you to use "find" command instead of "locate".*

I assume you installed via apt and because it has become a native package, CUDA is installed in a rather non-standard way.

They are installed into the root system paths: **/usr/bin**, **/usr/include**, **/usr/lib**
we need to emulate the old way for it to work. The following commands should do the trick:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/cuda /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI /usr/local/cuda/nvvm
sudo ln -s /usr/bin /usr/local/cuda/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/include /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda/lib64 /usr/local/cuda/lib
sudo ln -s /usr/include /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/include
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/libdevice /usr/local/cuda/nvvm/libdevice
```

**Resource:**
https://medium.com/@asmello/how-to-install-tensorflow-cuda-9-1-into-ubuntu-18-04-b645e769f01d