# NVIDIA driver installation. Need to update after each kernel update

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, updates, graphics

I have a GTX 1070. I downloaded the drivers from NVidia's official website and wanted to install them so I came across this post:[How to install NVIDIA.run?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149206/how-to-install-nvidia-run)

In the correct answer's comments it says that the drivers are reset everytime the kernel updates. So is there a way to install the drivers which wont need me to update them everytime after a kernel update
OS - UBUNTU 16.04 LTS

This is my first time installing graphic drivers on Ubuntu.

**EDIT**

I am installing drivers so I can use CUDA for deep learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is. The following installation guide provided [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036265/853882) by eromod will install NVidia Drivers and CUDA so that you don't need to update them manually (will be done by `apt update/upgrade`):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa

sudo apt update

sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

reboot

```
sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit gcc-6

nvcc --version
```

Comment: Be sure to totally uninstall the nVidia driver installed with the .run file. It should have instructions on how to do that. Otherwise you will get conflicts and major video issues. https://askubuntu.com/questions/219942/how-to-uninstall-manually-installed-nvidia-drivers

Comment: I used the additional drivers setting in ubuntu to get the drivers instead. CUDA works fine